# Why is my JPanel not being sized to JFrame when added?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, graphics2d

I am trying to make a program that displays a graph drawn with Graphics2D methods. I have a class entitled Model which contains financial information that I want to represent graphically. In the main method of the program, I make the following declaration and call,

```
m = new Model(stock, strike, interest, dividend, volatility, expiration);
m.addGraph(fSelect, vSelect);
```

The model function constructor just passes the arguments along to some fields inside the class. fSelect and vSelect inform a Graph class I created what function to graph and what variable to graph over. The addGraph method looks like,

```
 public void addGraph(int fSelection, int vSelection){
    //Why is my panel not showing up?
    graphPanel = new Graph(fSelection, vSelection, thisStock, thisStrike, thisInterest,
                         thisDividend, thisExpiration, thisVolatility);
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jf.add(graphPanel);
    jf.setSize(300, 300);
    graphPanel.drawGraph();
    jf.setVisible(true);
}
```

The Graph class extends the JPanel class. It's constructor looks like this,

```
public Graph(int whichFunction, int whichVariable, double whichStock, double whichStrike, double whichInterest, 
                double whichDividend, double whichExpiration, double whichVolatility){
    super();
    //...pass arguments into class fields
}
```

When I run the program, I get a blank JFrame. I haven't got a clue why it's blank. I have to be doing something wrong in the drawGraph method, or at least that's what I'm thinking the source of the problem is. The gist of the drawGraph method is,

```
 try{
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
     //draw stuff
     //...
     Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
     g2.dispose();
 }
 catch(Exception e) { }
```

I call a variety of Graphics2D methods, like fillRect, drawLine, etc., inside the try clause. Is this the proper way of drawing on a JPanel or am I missing something?

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics()` to do custom painting on a `Component`, override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method and do your drawings there .

Comment: In the future post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem when you ask a question.  Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). It contains working code you can download and play with.